# Posting the £ symbol (UK pound) using the Twitter API causing Update to Fail

Tags: php, twitter

I am using [Abraham's Twitter API](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) to post to Twitter (obviously).

Everything works great until I try to use a `£` in the tweet.

If I use `£` I get the error `Could not authenticate with OAuth`.

If I try using `&pound;` I literally get `&pound;` in the tweet.

I've tried using `utf8_encode` and `url_encode` and I've also just added a header to my script

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

but that didn't change anything either.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are typing with a UK keyboard into a document that is not saved as UTF-8, the it is unlikely the character will have the correct code point. Make sure your script is saved as UTF-8 without BOM. Although why this would affect the OAuth process I have no idea...

Comment: yeah, just checked, already saved as UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same exact problem and I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/twitter-development-talk/GXGM8Bo54aM). Basically I had to use the [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) function on the string which contained the pound sign.